# Protecting images from direct access by checking current PHP session with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, authorization, session, rewritemap

I'm working on a solution to a problem where users could potentially access images (in this case PDF files) stored in a folder off the server root. Normally, my application validates users through PHP scripts and sessions. What isn't happening right now is preventing non-logged in users from potentially accessing the PDFs.

The solution I'm looking for would (I think) need to be tied in with Apache. I saw an interesting solution using RewriteMap & RewriteRule, however the example involved putting this in an .htaccess file in the PDF directory. Can't do that with Apache (error: RewriteMap not allowed here). I believe the rewrite directives need to go in my httpd.conf, which I have access to.

So the example I found (that resulted in 'rewritemap not allowed here') is here:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap auth prg:auth.php
RewriteRule (.*) ${auth:$1}
```

auth.php just checks PHP session and redirects to a login script if needed.

I'm reading that I have to place this in my httpd.conf. How would I specify that the RewriteMap should only occur on a specific directory (including subdirectories)?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably handle it using RewriteRule instead of RewriteMap. Create a mod_rewrite rule that redirects pdf requests to a php file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*\.pdf)$ /path/to/auth.php?i=$1
```

You can then have the auth.php authenticate the session and spit out the actual contents of the PDF file. I did the same using a RewriteRule and jpg files.

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.[jJ].*)$ /auth.php.php?i=$1
```

I then uses auth.php to modify the image based on session and other factors and then spit it back out to the client. Eg:

```
$last_modified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime ($image));
header("Last-Modified: $last_modified");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image,NULL,95);
```

You can also do some cool things like adding a unique watermark and any other processing you'd like on the image and I suspect with the write functions, on a PDF file.

Comment: This is definitely the more flexible way of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap those directives in either a `<Location /directory>` block (if you want to match a URI) or a `<Directory /var/www/html/directory>` block (if you want to match a filesystem path).

Or you can just change the pattern part of the `RewriteRule` to only match the URI path you want:

```
RewriteRule (^/directory.*) ${auth:$1}
```